# NSFileHandle and scanf not echoing input in Xcode 4.5

Tags: cocoa, console, nsfilehandle, keyboard-input

I successfully use NSFileHandle to read keyboard input:

```
NSFileHandle * keyboard = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSData *inputData = [keyboard availableData];
NSString * input =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

As the user types, only the first character of input is echoed on the screen. For example, if I type `hello`, only `h` is echoed on the screen. However the full input is read into the string.

The proper echo behavior works in Xcode 4.2. I'm currently using Xcode 4.5.

**UPDATE**

Giving up on `NSFileHandle` for now, I tried to use `scanf`. However there's the same echoing issue. `scanf` code:

```
char word[4];
scanf("%s",word);
NSString * input = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:word length:4 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: What does your NSLog statement look like? Try changing all of the mutable stuff to non mutable. As for the enter key, substringWithRange will take it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Xcode 4.5. When the console is refreshed all echoed input is revealed.